# Using @Observable with .onReceive

Tags: swiftui

When I try to use `.onReceive()` on an `@Observable` property, for example:

```
private var myData = MyObservableObject()

VStack {
    //display stuff here
}
.onAppear {
    myData.fetchStuff()
}
.onReceive(myData.isReady) { //<--- Error!
    if myData.isDoneFetching {
        formatUIData()
    }
}
```

I get this error:

> Instance method 'onReceive(_:perform:)' requires that 'Bool' conform
> to 'Publisher'

is there a way to conform my property to `Publisher` so I can use `.onReceive()` or is this feature not viable with `@Observable`?

FYI, I know I can use `.onChange()` the same way here, but I'm interested in seeing if I can get `.onReceive()` working.

Comment: No, it comes with observation tracking for stuff like this. Combine is a limitation of Observable

Answer (score 1):

Formatting should be done in `body`, e.g.

```
Text(counter, format: .number)
.task {
    counter = await myData.fetchStuff()
}
```